# Why mvn dependency:tree sometimes download the binary files?

Tags: maven

In my opinion, we can get the dependency tree by analyzing the pom.xml files recursively without the binary files of these dependencies. However, I find that maven sometimes will download some binary files when I run `mvn dependency:tree`. Why are these files downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

Might be because maven dependency plugin has its own dependencies:

```
> [INFO]
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
> [INFO] +-
> org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
> [INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
> [INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
> [INFO] |        \-
> (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for
> conflict with 2.0)
```

More detail is in [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Comment: Damn! Mind blown! Ofcourse, makes sense!

Comment: @MarcoPolo, please consider a upvote! :)